# jQuery toggle .on() and .off() with scrolling

Tags: jquery

I don't know how I should do this. I have a scrollTo effect on a button. But I only want to fire it when the user is on the top of the page. When he leaves the "height", I want to turn it of. If he comes back into the "height" I want to turn it back on.

I tried this jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){
         $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 220 }, "slow");
    });

});

var height = $(window).height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > height) {
        $('navbar-toggle').off('click');
    } else {
        $('navbar-toggle').on('click');

    }
});
```

But it's not working and I don't know how to fix it. Would be great if you guys could help me out! :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in your code..
first, you shouldn't do

```
$('navbar-toggle').off('click');
```

**the handler is missing**, this means that **all** click events for that elements will be dismissed.

Plus, the dot is missing in the selector, it should be $`('.navbar-toggle')`

So, i suggest to save your function into a variable, like this:

```
var myHandler = function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 220 }, "slow");
};
```

then you can easily do:

```
$('.navbar-toggle').on('click', myHandler);
$('.navbar-toggle').off('click', myHandler);
```

> But I only want to fire it when the user is on the top of the page

To do this you don't need to calculate height, but just check `if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0)`

The final code should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var myHandler = function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 220 }, "slow");
   };

   $('.navbar-toggle').on('click', myHandler);

   $(window).scroll(function() {
       if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
           $('.navbar-toggle').off('click', myHandler);
       } else {
           $('.navbar-toggle').on('click', myHandler);
       }
   });
});
```

Check out the [DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/3fxa04no/)

Comment: Oh yes! 
Thank you, great way to do this!